# PHP - is it possible to use custom exception handler (set_exception_handler) inside a __destruct() method?

Tags: php

Is there way to use a custom exception handler, instead of the default exception handler, inside a class's `__destruct` method?

For example:

```
function myExceptionHandler($e)
{
    echo "custom exception handler";
    if(is_object($e) && method_exists($e,'getMessage'))
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
set_exception_handler('myExceptionHandler');
class MyClass {
    public function __construct()
    {
        // myExceptionHandler handles this exception
        //throw new Exception("Exception from " . __METHOD__);
    }

    public function doStuff()
    {
        // myExceptionHandler handles this exception
        //throw new Exception("Exception from " . __METHOD__);
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        // default exception handler 
        throw new Exception("Exception from " . __METHOD__);
    }

}

$myclass = new MyClass();
$myclass->doStuff();
```

Even if `set_exception_handler` is called within the `__destruct` method, the default handler is still used:

```
    public function __destruct()
    {
        $callable = function($e)
        {
            echo "custom exception handler".PHP_EOL;
            if(is_object($e) && method_exists($e,'getMessage'))
                echo $e->getMessage();
        };
        set_exception_handler($callable);
        throw new Exception("Exception from " . __METHOD__); // default exception handler
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual page](https://www.php.net/__construct)

> **Note:**
>
> Attempting to throw an exception from a destructor (called in the time
> of script termination) causes a fatal error.

So using exceptions in a destructor is probably a bad idea in the first place.  There may not be any of your code around when the script has finished to process the exception that is thrown.

Perhaps this code would be better placed in a `close()` method of the class instead.

Comment: thanks, yes I ended up doing something similar to a ```close()``` method

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
<?php

class MyException extends Exception {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('my exception');
    }
}

class MyClass {
    public function __construct()
    {
        // myExceptionHandler handles this exception
        //throw new Exception("Exception from " . __METHOD__);
    }

    public function doStuff()
    {
        // myExceptionHandler handles this exception
        //throw new Exception("Exception from " . __METHOD__);
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        // default exception handler 
        throw new MyException();
    }

}

$myclass = new MyClass();
$myclass->doStuff();
```

Comment: I don't think this works either (tried something similar). Per Nigel and the manual, it's not possible (and perhaps not desirable)